# Project compiled on an older version, how to have it runnable on any computer?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

My application uses SQLite and the JDBC driver.When I export my .jar from Eclipse it doesn't run on my computer because it's on an older version of Java. I could downgrade Java, but then I can't have it run on other people's computers without them having to downgrade Java. I can't update compiler because SQLite and JDBC driver need an older version of Java.

How to have it runnable on any computer?

Comment: You can set the 'Compiler compliance level' in the Java Compiler section of the project Properties - that sets the level of Java to use.

Comment: You create a JAR file from your Eclipse project and you create an installer to install the Java runtime, your JAR, and SQLite.

Comment: I think the reason your question was downvoted is that it's not quite full. If you have already tried what you intended to do, why didn't you post the results? Any errors? Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the tour and read [ask] and its linked resources

Comment: compiled Java programs can usually run on any newer version of java, they usually even compile with newer versions  as well. What kind of error do you get when you try to run it on a new version?